# Boto urllib2 URLError (Caught exception reading instance data)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, urllib2, boto

I am using `common_crawl_index` lib for python from [here](https://github.com/wiseman/common_crawl_index) to get some data from `S3`.

When I run the command to get data `cci_lookup com.abc` it has error as below.

I still get the output that is the list of urls for the lookup domain but I do not know why the error happen.

```
MainThread:2014-12-19 01:48:16,150:ERROR:utils:224 Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 211, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req)
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
com.abc.www/forum/index.php/groupcp.php:http
com.abc.www/forum/index.php/includes/MLOtvHD:http
com.abc.www/forum/index.php/includes/blog.php:http
com.abc.www/forum/index.php/includes/content.php:http
com.abc.www/forum/index.php/includes/index.php:http
```

Hope anyone can help!